# Transfering Apps from Apple Developer account to Apple Enterprise Account

Tags: ios, enterprise

My company uses Apple Developer account to distribute an app and it is live. Now my company give me an Apple Enterprise account in order to export that same app from the Apple Developer account for testing with wider range of users without 100 UUID devices limitation.

My Question is how can i export this app using enterprise account because i want to use the same bundle ID for payment, purchase and keeping that app on the Appstore?

Comment: Is it an enterprise account or a company developer account?  If it is an enterprise account then distribution takes place outside the App Store and there is no payment or in-app purchase, so you can simply create a new app.  Company developer accounts are for distribution through the app store.  They have payment and in-app purchase capabilities but still have a 100 device limit.  If you want to test on more devices, you can use TestFlight.

Comment: FYI, For an enterprise account, you don't have an access to iTunesConnect/TestFlight.

Comment: Think you will need to change to new bundle ID to sign your app again with enterprise account, then you can export it as ipa

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question.

Comment: @Paulw11 No IAP and payment capabilities for enterprise account? i need to keep the same bundle id for other service like login system, crash&Log system, atc.. are there anyway for this?

Comment: Again, you need to clarify if you are talking about enterprise or company developer membership; they are different things.  With the enterprise program you can use any bundle ID you want as distribution happens outside the store, so you can continue using the same bundle id but there is no iTunesConnect, no payment and no IAP.  With a company membership you can transfer the app from your personal membership as long as you have at least one version released to the store.  In this case you can keep the bundle and any IAP.  There is still a 100 device limit for ad-hoc install though

Comment: @Paulw11Enterprise account can use any bundle ID? is that true? because i want to use the bundle id from the app using company developer membership for the enterprise account app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upload new application on Enterprise account, You cannot use the option of transfer app which is available in iTunes account. Create all the certificates and profiles the same way you created on developers account. Use the enterprise option when creating profiles.

Transfer can be only be done by this way.

Comment: I can't keep the bundle ID for purchase and push notification?

Comment: Yes, you can't.

Comment: Purchase id of products are linked with developer account and that is not available in Enterprise account. Enterprise account allow you to spread application without appstore.